# Unable to install JavaFX into a Spring project using STS

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I'm attempting to create a desktop based app using STS, and I want to use JavaFX for the front end components, but attempting to install gives the following error

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: e(fx)clipse - IDE - Basic 1.1.0.201411050807 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.basic.feature.feature.group 1.1.0.201411050807)
  Software currently installed: Spring Tool Suite 3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Fake bundle for Javafx 2.2.0.201411050602 (org.eclipse.fx.javafx 2.2.0.201411050602)
    Fake bundle for Javafx 2.2.0.201408150502 (org.eclipse.fx.javafx 2.2.0.201408150502)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: e(fx)clipse - IDE - Basic 1.1.0.201411050807 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.basic.feature.feature.group 1.1.0.201411050807)
    To: org.eclipse.fx.javafx [2.2.0.201411050602]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring Dashboard (optional) 3.6.3.201411271001-RELEASE (org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.feature.group 3.6.3.201411271001-RELEASE)
    To: org.eclipse.fx.javafx [2.2.0.201408150502]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring Tool Suite 3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44)
    To: org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group [3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring Tool Suite Package 3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44 (org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group 3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44)
    To: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.feature.group 0.0.0
```

So in a nutshell, is Java FX compatible with Spring/STS and if so how I can get past this error message?

Comment: I suggest you ask your answer on the [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/259/) support forums.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, it looks like the cause is:

```
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Fake bundle for Javafx 2.2.0.201411050602 (org.eclipse.fx.javafx 2.2.0.201411050602)
    Fake bundle for Javafx 2.2.0.201408150502 (org.eclipse.fx.javafx 2.2.0.201408150502)
```

Since the only Spring IDE component using the this `Fake bundle for Javafx` seems to be the Spring Dashboard, you can have e(fx)clipse play nice with Spring if you remove (or ommit) the installation of the Spring Dashboard.

So the answer is yes, JavaFx is compatible with the Spring IDE (STS).

Steps to install:

1. Get a clean Eclipse install.
2. Install e(fx)clipse.
3. Install Spring STS disabling the Dashboard on the confirmation page.